# Approve an email before sending

Tags: email, servicecloud, approval-process

In our business, we want when our L1 agents send email as a reply to a case they should go through approval of their managers. So when they create a reply they put customer email address in to, write the mail body, attach files as required and finally, when clicks the send button, it should not be dispatched. Rather it should go to their manager. And they can actually send the email after editing if required.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a custom object, child object of Case, in which the L1 agents create the reply and add attachments to it (it would also contain the email address (formula) of the customer). You can then have an approval process on this object to route it to an approver and then once it gets approved, you could then send your email using a flow, process or apex.

Comment: Thanks Jitender. So it means L1 users can not use standard screen for emailing. Or they can?

Comment: No, they will not. They would instead be creating a custom object record.